# ComboBox without selection item. Only popup checkboxes

Tags: .net, xaml, checkbox, uwp, combobox

I have a comboBox. When opened it shows checkboxes.

Problem: While checking/unchecking one becomes selected item for my comboBox. I don't want that.

- I want to disable selectable item, because logic is done when checking/unchecking items in comboBox's popup.
- And preferably default text "-- Select flags --".

[image]

[image]

[image]

I tried:

- IsReadOnly property does not exist. Cannot be selected. Maybe its due to my ItemTemplate because its not - TextBox (I don't know).
- IsEditable="False" does not work
- IsHitTestVisible, IsEnabled="False" make it unopenable. I cannot get to check boxes

```
            <ComboBox Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" 
                Name="flagComboBox" IsTextSearchEnabled="True" Margin="0,10,0,0"
                IsEditable="False" Text="-- Select flags -- (does not show)"
                >
                <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate >
                        <CheckBox Name="checkFileException"
                            Checked="Check_Flag" Unchecked="Uncheck_Flag" 
                            Content="{Binding}" 
                            CommandParameter="{Binding}"
                            >
                        </CheckBox>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
            </ComboBox>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this:

**In XAML**, first, change

```
Text="-- Select flags -- (does not show)"
```

with

```
PlaceholderText="-- Select flags --"
```

Then, add an event when the user change selection in the ComboBox

```
SelectionChanged="ComboBox_SelectionChanged"
```

**In your code**, add:

```
private void ComboBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        flagComboBox.SelectedIndex = -1;

    }
```

The user will see the PlaceholderText in the ComboBox

**EDIT:**
If you want to keep open the ComboBox until the user press anywhere else on the screen (so the user will continue to see the ComboBox even if clicks on the text) you could do a workaround:

In your **XAML** file, add three events to the ComboBox:

```
GotFocus="flagComboBox_GotFocus" LostFocus="flagComboBox_LostFocus" DropDownClosed="flagComboBox_DropDownClosed"
```

**In code**, create a new `bool` that indicates if the user is using the ComboBox

```
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    bool isPointerOnComboBox = false; // <-- add the bool here
    public MainPage()
```

Then, add these three voids

```
private void flagComboBox_DropDownClosed(object sender, object e)
    {
        if (isPointerOnComboBox.Equals(true))
        {
            flagComboBox.IsDropDownOpen = true;
        }
    }

    private void flagComboBox_GotFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        isPointerOnComboBox = true;
    }

    private void flagComboBox_LostFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        isPointerOnComboBox = false;
    }
```

If the ComboBox got focus (it was selected by the user), the ComboBox will reopen automatically. If the ComboBox hasn't got focus (the user clicked somewhere else), the ComboBox won't reopen.

Comment: Perfection! 
A problem remains: If a person clicks between checkboxes after some clicks, one will activate selection and the popup closes. Which can be annoying. I think its hard to solve this issue.

Comment: @MihaiSocaciu I edited the original post with a workaround to keep the ComboBox open until the user clicks in any other space, so, if the user clicks to the ComboBox item's text, the ComboBox's checkboxes will continue to be visible

Comment: After above changes, the selection still closes popup. And I cannot click outside only after checking. Made a GIF:
https://imgur.com/a/1138jP3

Comment: @MihaiSocaciu You could  try `if (! isPointerOnComboBox)  { flagComboBox.IsDropDownOpen = false;}` in the `DropDownClosed` event.

Comment: "DropDownClosed" is called before "LostFocus", so it opens infinitely. So I will abandon that part. And the main bug about selection change closing pop up dialog is still unsolved.
But your effort helped me solve the main problems. Gonna mark it solved. Thanks!